# Visual Studio shortcuts in VS 2010 and VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In in development experience, strange thing I am finding having a PC in a Bank and 3 times it has got errors and changed, and now I am finding issues in VS editors, that for example, short cuts like CTRL KU for uncommenting, and commenting multiple lines together doesn't work properly and my fast typing hands using such short cuts find it difficult to perform activities.

Also, I couldn't do "Undo" of code changes which is very very scary as I used to do a lot of code changes and save and run and again I used to successfully undo everything even though its saved. But I am finding these all not happening in this PC/organization for VS.

I tried googling out for any settings to enable for these features, but futile, as I see not much settings on these found. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Is the ASP.NET MVC installed?

Comment: I just installed VS 2010 and VS 2012. How to install ASP.NET MVC ? I checked framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 is installed

Comment: Try resetting all Visual Studio settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings)

Comment: @VikasRana: Performed, no luck. Strange thing is, whenever I select from middle of line, the freaking VS comments only until that character (This problem I never had). It used to comment all the whole line. FREAKS me OUT !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: have you tried updating the keyboard mapping scheme under tools>options

Comment: I'd recommend using [`ReSharper`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).  It offers a different Keyboard Shortcut scheme and the possibility to keep the Visual Studio scheme. Overall this is one of the best tools for programming, once you've used it you won't be able to live without. It's extremely helpful for stuff like code cleanup.

Comment: @Oceans: Mate, please answer for the question. I don't care about Resharper or whatever, I never used those and I was happy with VS sort cuts. Now I am frustrated I couldn't do everything with keys. I can comment, but when I start in the middle select it, it comments only those portion and not the entire line

Comment: @amitdayama: Thank you, it worked :) I chose C# 2005, but I was already exploring this option yesterday but couldn;'t figure out, even MSDN doesn't have clear guidance on this. This is the stupid problem I experienced with Microsoft. All good now except the commenting of whole line even if I start in middle in the XML config files which is not happening. It happens in C# code files though :) I think since I chose C# 2005, it is doing good there but not in XML files (I reckon). If you know any answer on this, please drop thanks

Comment: That's great.. Please check the answer given below if it doesn't help let me know :)

Comment: @amitdayama: I have rated your answer mate. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under visual studio
GO to the Tools> Options
A window will pop up. Under Environment choose keyboard.
Make sure visual C# 2005 is selected.

For Comment/Uncomment in your xml file. Make Sure following settings are present there

[image: This image shows the settings for uncomment selection]

You might have noticed that "Use New shortcut in" is "Global". In your case it might be something else.
Do the same for Edit.commentselection